# Diff and patch didn't works as expected

Tags: linux, diff, patch

Everytime when i try copy a file out from a folder, do some change and patch it, it always trys to patch into the new file. Why?

```
$ mkdir test
$ vim test/1 (Write something)
$ cp test/1 ./1
$ vim 1 (Do some change)
$ diff -Naur test/1 1 > patch
$ patch -p0 < patch
   pathing file 1
   Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
```

Comment: BTW Linux has [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)), not folders

Answer (score 0):

**Read *carefully* [patch(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1.html) and [diff(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html).**

`patch` works (by default) in the current working directory. But you invoke `diff` on (a patch from) some other directory. Try with `diff -Naur 1 test/1 > patch`, it could work better. Order of arguments to `diff` matters a big lot !

Comment: `diff -Naur 1 test/1 > patch`  and `diff -Naur test/1 1> patch` have same result. They all try to edit 1, why...

Comment: I don't observe that. Are you really sure? Did you try `diff -Naur 1 test/1 > patcha` and also `diff -Naur test/1 1 > patchb`  and then run `diff patcha patchb` or `cmp patcha patchb` to check that they are not the same or compare their checksum, e.g. as given by `md5sum patcha` and `md5sum patchb` ?

Comment: BTW good editors have also the ability to show differences. For example `emacs` has a very useful *ediff* mode. Consider using that.

Comment: This two patch files from diff is different. They have different order of files. But the problem is whatever which version is givend, patch always try to patch the new file !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please excute my commands as a same order in my Questions, you will get a same result. I know it's my fault, but I don't know where is the problem.